# Foreign Key sharing in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

My database is composed of two tables: `Organisation` and `User`, in a `ManyToOne` relationship, where an organisation can hold many users.

Before I share my problem, here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organisation")
public class OrganisationEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "orga_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = OrganisationEntity.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "orga_id")
    private OrganisationEntity organisation;

    // Getters & Setters    
}
```

Here is my issue, when two users are assigned an organisation with the **same** name, said organisation is created twice in the `Organisation` table with 2 different ID's. I wish to assign an organisation's ID to a new user if it already exists.

So if users U1 & U2 are created with an organisation called O1, both should have the same `orga_id` and only one organisation entry should be created in the database.

How can that be achieved? And what is missing in my understanding of `Hibernate`?

*On request*, here is my service that creates the `UserEntity` upon user registration:

```
@Override
public UserInfo createUser(UserInfo newUser) {
    return mapper.map(userDao.save(mapper.map(newUser)));
}
```

I map the object with `Mapstruct` to a `UserEntity` and send it to my `DAO` in order to save it in my database.

Comment: Could you please post the code that creates/updates entities as well?

Comment: I have added my service, please let me know if that is not enough.

Comment: You mentioned that you assign two users to an organization with the "same" name, which leads me to believe you're creating two Organization instances, and you're giving both the same name, which doesn't tell hibernate in any way that they are actually the same Organization. You should instantiate 1 Organization and assign it to both users. Can you post the code where you are creating the the OrganizationEntity and the UserEntity?

Comment: Yeah as each new object for Organisation will create objects with different ID's when saving to the DB and thus they will be treated as different objects. You can use the unique constrain to stop the same organisation value to persist in the Organisation table again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't assign a new `Organisation` instance each time a new user is created, but rather that you first query the DB for an existing organisation by name, and re-use the resulting entity for all related users if it's already there.

Additionally, for the sake of correctness, consider adding a `UNIQUE` constraint to the `organisation.name` column.

Comment: Where should that query be done? In the DAO? instead of "just" saving to the DB, I create a method that would check AND save?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want different Oraganisations for different users, it's better to remove `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` from `Id` attribute of `OrganisationEntity`. This would prevent creating more Organisation entries in DB.

Also fetch OrganisationEntity object first and assign to UserEntity

Comment: Understood, it would then not create entries at all, would it?